# Definition of a graph of a function question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

> Definition:
>
> A graph $G_f$ of a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a subset
> of $A\times  \mathbb{R} $ with notation: $G_f = \{(x,y)\in
>  A\times\mathbb{R}; y = f(x) \}$

I do not understand what does $A \times \mathbb{R}$ actually mean.

Comment: [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\times \mathbb{R}$ is the cartesian product and it's defined by $$A\times \mathbb{R}=\{(x,y): x\in A \wedge y\in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

In this case for example, we have that

1. If $f:  \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$, so we have that $$\operatorname{G}_{f}=\{(x,y)\in \Omega\times \mathbb{R}: x\in \Omega \wedge y\in \mathbb{R}\}$$and $\operatorname{G}_{f}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{1+1}$.
2. If $f: \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x+y$, so we have that $$\operatorname{G}_{f}=\{(x,y)\in \Omega\times \mathbb{R}: z=f(x,y)\}$$and $\operatorname{G}_{f}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2+1}$.